# Changing vagrant ssh user creates permission erros

Tags: ssh, debian, virtualbox, vagrant

I'm trying to alter an Vagrant box I created for my office. Currently, like most boxes, running `vagrant ssh` logins me in as the `vagrant` user, but team members get frustrated having to use `su - xxadmin` to switch to our primary admin user.

In my Vagrantfile, I added: `config.ssh.username = "xxadmin"`, but then I started receiving the common Vagrant error when running `vagrant up`:

```
[default] Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

sed -e '/^#VAGRANT-BEGIN/,/^#VAGRANT-END/ d' /etc/network/interfaces > /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

and when running `vagrant halt`:

```
[default] Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

shutdown -h now

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

**What's going on here? Why would simply changing the ssh user create these errors? How do i find a solution forward?**

Specs:

- OS X Mavericks (host)
- Vagrant 1.3.5
- Virtualbox 4.3.2
- Debian 7 Wheezy (vm client)

Answer (score 2):

In your box, you need to modify your sudoers file by running `visudo` and adding the following:

```
Defaults    !requiretty
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept running into this error until I made sure that my user's NOPASSWD sudoers entry was not being [squashed](https://askubuntu.com/a/340669/370397).